# Writing to file that is placed in resource folder of my java webapplication

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

Basically I'm trying to build an HTML file and return as a standalone webpage for a webservice call. I have challenges here:

1. How to return a HTML file so that the browser will be able to view that as an HTML page?
2. How to refer this file in my code, and build it dynamically?

Note: I did come across a solution for my first point: " to return as an input stream". However while calling the webservice, I noticed the file downloading directly. But its not in .html. It's just a file which I need to edit it to change to .html and then view.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The way you have asked the question, I would also recommend to download html file in response. Can you explain your scenario of webservice returning a html page with example?

Comment: A webservice call to render a page in the browser? What kind of webservice call?

Comment: I understand that this is something unusual. But this is a demanding requirement. I tried to do this 

"ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("web/admin/testFood.html"));

return reader;

But the challenge is that this only returns as in Inputstream. I"m not able to refer this a file from which i can use a file writer and edit

Comment: @ Gaurava: Here is an example: The user fires a URL say " something/getMeThisService/

And the respone is going to be a standalone HTML page, which has the necessary details and also a link to download a XML equivalent of the response. This xml would be used by the user should he needs it for some purpose to upload into this own applicaiton